# Android java : Draw polyline on Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, draw, polyline

I want to draw a polyline on a Bitmap which contains a picture but I don't know if I can draw a polyline on a Bitmap.
Any idea ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Using draw canvas

Comment: OK but which method should I use ?

Comment: `Canvas#drawPath`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following function:

```
canvas.drawLines(float[] pts, 
            int offset, 
            int count, 
            Paint paint);
```

OR

```
canvas.drawPath(Path path, 
                Paint paint);
```

Check below links for more details:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLines(float[], int, int, android.graphics.Paint)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath(android.graphics.Path, android.graphics.Paint)